# Pegar conteúdo de dentro de uma Div e colocar no value do Input

Tags: javascript, html, div, input

Eu tenho um form, e dentro dele tenho um input, que terá que pegar o que contém dentro de uma DIV, que no caso é só texto.

O input está assim:

```
<input class='formContato' type='text' name='orcamentoAssuntoForm' id='orcamentoAssuntoForm' value='Assunto'/>
```

No caso, o conteúdo dessa div deve estar dentro do `value`.

A `div` no caso está assim:

```
<div class="produtosIntTitulo margin-top-30">Produto teste 1</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz com `Jquery` para você dar uma olhada de como pegar o texto da `div`

***Jquery***

```
$(function(){
    var valorDaDiv = $(".produtosIntTitulo").text();    
    $("#orcamentoAssuntoForm").val(valorDaDiv);
});
```

Você pode acompanhar o resultado nesta **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/ZS7Xy/)**

Comment: Funcionou 100%. Obrigado.

Comment: No meu caso eu preciso fazer login em uma outra página e pegar o conteudo de uma div. Você sabe como eu poderia fazer o login?

Comment: Preciso de mais detalhes pra poder te dar a resposta @DevidyOliviera

Comment: @DiegoVieira eu preciso de uma função javascript/ jQuery que vai fazer login em outro site e pegar o conteudo de uma DIV. Tenho essa pergunta aqui que explica melhor (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54703/fazer-login-em-um-site-via-jquery-javascript?noredirect=1#comment112426_54703)

Answer (score 1):

No caso do formulário você usará o `val()` para realizar o set e na div utilizará o `text()` para realizar o get.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( '.formContato' ).val($( '.produtosIntTitulo' ).text());
});
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyamarante/V4ebK/**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode capturar e alterar o valor de uma div usando `getElementById()`.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function alteraDiv(){
                    var destino = document.getElementById("minhadiv");
                    destino.value = document.getElementById("orcamentoAssuntoForm").value;;
              }
        </script>
```

Fazendo uma função javascript para isso, você poderia chamar ela para em algum evento do seu *input* (no *onchange* por exemplo)

```
         <input class='formContato' type='text' name='orcamentoAssuntoForm' id='orcamentoAssuntoForm' value='Assunto' onchange="alteraDiv()"/>

         <div id="minhadiv" class="produtosIntTitulo margin-top-30">Produto teste 1</div>
```

Comment: Poderia fazer usando `document.querySelector` do ECMA5 para não poluir com ID e manter suas classes :)

Answer (score 1):

Com `javascript` puro, sem o uso de `jQuery` seria assim:

```js
var produtosIntTitulo = document.getElementsByClassName("produtosIntTitulo");
var orcamentoAssuntoForm = document.getElementById("orcamentoAssuntoForm");
orcamentoAssuntoForm.value = produtosIntTitulo[0].innerText;
```

[Demo online.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/KJ75e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar apenas JavaScript puro para fazer isto se preferir...

```
   window.onload = function(){
        var divconteudo = document.getElementsByClassName("produtosIntTitulo margin-top-30")[0].textContent;
        document.getElementById("orcamentoAssuntoForm").value = divconteudo;
    };
```