# Pegar Valor da Label Div Filha

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(".Linha").on('click', function(){
   // Como pegar o Valor da Parcela ao Clicar na Div
    
});
```

```html
     // Como pegar o Valor da Parcela ao Clicar na Div

  <div class="Linha row align-vertical" style="height: 389px; overflow: auto;" >
                            <!-- RECEBE DIVS DINAMICAS -->
           <div class="table" style="border: 1px solid; border-color:#E6E6E6; 
                margin:10px; width:200px; height:350px; text-align:center;"> 
                Valor da Parcela</label><br><label id="1" 
                Class="dp1">111.567</label> 
           </div>
           <div class="table" style="border: 1px solid; border-color:#E6E6E6; 
                margin:10px; width:200px; height:350px; text-align:center;"> 
                Valor da Parcela</label><br><label id="2" 
                class="dp1">141.967</label> 
           </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você consegue pegar o valor da `label` pelo seu **id** ou pela sua **classe**, **mas já adianto que sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada**, pois já existem diversas perguntas parecidas como a sua de como se capturar texto, value, etc... aqui no site.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar conteúdo de dentro de uma Div e colocar no value do Input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25303/pegar-conte%c3%bado-de-dentro-de-uma-div-e-colocar-no-value-do-input)

Comment: Pq está fechando um label ser tê-lo aberto: `Valor da Parcela</label>`?

Comment: Não conseguir achar uma pergunta do que preciso, por isso que abrir. O Examplo que você  passou não me atende. Mais Mesmo assim Obrigado. Irei procurar em outro Lugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.Linha').on('click', () => {
  const productContent = document.querySelectorAll('.dp1')
  const price = []
  
  for(let i = 0; i < productContent.length; i++){
    price.push(productContent[i].firstChild.textContent)
  }
})
```