# Guardar texto de uma TEXTAREA com botão e imprimir em outra div

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Como eu salvo um texto de uma Textarea em uma variável com um clique em um botão, e depois imprimo esse texto clicando com outro botão em outra textarea?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar conteúdo de dentro de uma Div e colocar no value do Input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25303/pegar-conte%c3%bado-de-dentro-de-uma-div-e-colocar-no-value-do-input)

Answer (score 3):

bom dia. Explicarei o passo a passo conforme suas perguntas.

> Como salvo um texto de uma TextArea em uma variável?

Nossos input's e botão:

```
<input id="primeiroInput">
<button id="insertButton" onclick="myFunction()">Insere no outro Input</button>
<input id="segundoInput">
```

Utilizando JS puro podemos primeiro ter acesso ao elemento primeiroInput e armazenar na variável x com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
var x = document.getElementById("primeiroInput").value;
```

Segunda parte da pergunta:

> ...e depois imprimo esse texto clicando com outro botão em outra textarea?

Com isso temos armazenado na variável x o valor do seu input agora precisamos definir o que o evento de click do nosso botão fará:

```
function myFunction(){
var x = document.getElementById("primeiroInput").value;
document.getElementById('segundoInput').value = x;
};
```

Resumidamente: Criamos uma função com nome "myFunction" e dentro dela temos a parte que pegamos o valor do "primeiroInput" e passamos este valor para o "segundoInput". Perceba que na criação do botão inserimos no evento "onclick" a função "myFunction".

Neste caso não precisamos de dois botões conforme sua pergunta. Aliás conseguimos fazer até sem botões apenas usando o evento onchange do input.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços